# the string doesn't display the content in javascript

Tags: javascript

my code is not working and does not display the content inside the while loop, [the output should look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KazaI.png)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>js</title>
<script> 

var counter=1;

while(counter <= 7){

document.writeln("<p style = font-size: "+ counter +"ex'>Html5 font size +" counter +"ex </p>");

 ++counter;

}

</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
```

Comment: It looks like you are potentially writing a p tag as a child of the head tag, which is not a visible element

Comment: As @Taplar said move the code from <head> tag.